# Style first line of a table cell in Google Docs using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to style the first line in a table cell while appending the table to the document body using [`appendTable`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendtablecells). I can't seem to find a way to format text while using this method.

I've tried using ranges, but it seems inefficient like there would be a faster better way to do this.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name');
var body = doc.getBody();

var cells = [];
    row1cell1 = cell1Data + "\n" + //color the first line
                cell1MetaData;

    row1cell2 = cell2Data + "\n" + //bold the first line
                cell2MetaData;

    row1cell3 = cell3Data + "\n" + //italics the first line
                cell3MetaData;

cells.push([row1cell1,row1cell2,row1cell3]);
body.appendTable(cells);
```

I don't want to append the table and then go find the tables that I have just appended using ranges just to format a line that I am handling already.

Comment: `body.appendTable(cells);` returns the table. So you can just continue on that by adding your styling.